# How cast type when the original arg is a pointer

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

So I have this:

```
v, ok := muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map").(map[string]interface{})
```

the problem is that:

```
muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map")
```

returns a pointer.  I tried dereferencing the pointer like so:

```
(*(muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map"))
```

but I get this:

```
Invalid indirect of '(muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map"))' (type 'interface{}')
```

so I suppose since the Get method doesn't return a pointer, then I can't dereference it.

Comment: It looks like `muxctx.Get` returns an interface{}. If you know the type of that interface, you can type-assert to that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you want something like:

```
// You really want this to be two variables, lest you go mad.
// OK here is mostly to see whether the value exists or not, which is what
// presumably you're testing for.  Get that out of the way before trying to
// get fancy with type coercion.
//
ptr, ok := muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map")

... // Do other stuff (like your if test maybe)...

// Now coerce and deref.  We coerce the type inside parens THEN we try to
// dereference afterwards.
//
v := *(ptr.(*map[string]interface{}))
```

A brief example of this general technique:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    foo := 10
    var bar interface{}
    bar = &foo
    fmt.Println(bar)
    foobar := *(bar.(*int))
    fmt.Println(foobar)
}

$ ./spike
0xc00009e010
10
```

Finally, be really sure you have the type you want (using reflection if needbe) or risk the program panic'ing on a bad type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

Get method is `func (m *muxctx) Get(string) interface{}`, return a value type is interface{}, if value is int(1) type is interface{}, if value is map[string]interface{} type return type also interface{}.

so ptr type is interface{} in  `ptr, ok := muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map")`, must convert interface{} ptr type a need type,example map[string]interface{}:`ptr.(*map[string]interface{})`, map ptr? `ptr.(map[string]interface{})`, map double ptr? `ptr.(**map[string]interface{})`

`(*(muxctx.Get(req, "req-body-map"))` convert code is invalid syntax, `var i interface{}; *i`,i type is interface{}, not use * remove pointer,must convert i to a ptr type, example:`n := i.(*int); *n` or `m := i.(*map[string]interface{}); *m`.

golang spce doc:

[Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

[Type switches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches)。

[unsafe](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe)

[Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)